# Why can’t I delete the TV application from macOS Ventura?

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to delete Apple TV on my 14-inch 2021 Macbook Pro M1, Ventura OS 13.1 version.

Running this command in my terminal:

```
sudo rm -Rdf /System/Applications/TV.app
```

Returns "Operation not permitted". I have also tried dragging the app from the Applications folder to the bin without success, and if I right-click there is no 'Move to Bin' option.

This is my first experience with macOS after using Linux for many years and it is very frustrating.

What can I do to remove the TV application from macOS?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better suited for the [Apple specific SE site](https://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: This is odd. There is a great of macOS software called [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) that I typically use to delete files and related system config stuff from macOS including many default macOS applications like Garage Band. But when I launched it just now and attempted to delete the TV application, it showed all of the TV related files it could delete and the TV application itself had a padlock icon.

Comment: A note on your bounty: we don't really do pros/cons here. // The app is most likely protected as part of the operating system, with _System Integrity Protection_.

Answer (score 1):

Apple TV itself is part of macOS and can’t be deleted,
only worked-around (disabled/hidden).

You may
[remove its icon from the Dock](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/open-apps-from-the-dock-mh35859/13.0/mac/13.0) :

> Drag the item out of the Dock until Remove is shown. Only the alias is removed; the actual item remains on your Mac.

You can set up [Screen Time](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210387)
to block access to it.
The article
[The 3 Best Ways to Lock Apps and Limit Screen Time on iPad and iPhone in 2022](https://www.ursor.com/blog/the-3-best-ways-to-lock-apps-and-limit-screen-time-on-ipad-and-iphone-in-2022)
lists the following methods:

- Setting "Time Limits"
- Locking the app
- Locking using "Guided Access"

References :

- [Can I uninstall Apple TV from my Mac?](https://www.comoapple.com/how-to-uninstall-apple-tv-from-macbook-air-2.html#Can_I_uninstall_Apple_TV_from_my_Mac)
- [cannot remove AppleTV from Mac](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251854788)
- [HOW DO I DELETE APPLE TV FROM MY MACBOOK AIR WITH CATALINA VERS 10.15.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251868123)

Comment: Do you know how to disable its function + A keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove or uninstall TV.app on Mac.

If your main concern is the TV folder in ~/Movies, that is automatically being created even if you don't use the TV app.

```
chflags hidden ~/Movies/TV
```

Above command will hide it from Finder

Comment: This folder is the app's library. Hold down 'alt' while launching the app and you can place it somewhere else, like inside the `Library` folder.